# Apache rewrite example.com/forum to be example.com/index.php?page=forum

Tags: mod-rewrite

Im a complete beginner with Apache re-writes.

Im trying to get example.com/forum to be example.com/index.php?page=forum

Here is my rewrite file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/forum$ index.php?page=forum

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is what worked - RewriteRule ^forum$ index.php?page=forum [L] My problem was I had a URL handling script which would again to a URL rewrite. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thank you but I only want to rewrite /forum not for example /foo-bar

Comment: @nullptr - In that case, isn't your htaccess already working? All I can think up is adding the `[L]` flag to the end of `RewriteRule` you have written.

Comment: You could be right, the other rules are auto generated by wordpress so I have no idea what going on

Comment: @nullptr - Try doing this `RewriteRule ^/forum$ index.php?page=forum [L]`. see if this works.